# Need query in order to get specific result

Tags: sql

I have following table.

```
locationName    itemnumber  pickRouteOrder
     loc1            item1           10
     loc2            item2           20
     loc2            item3           20
     loc4            item5           30
     no-loc          item6           99
     no-loc          item7           99
```

Need to show all records if  locationName=noLoc.
If locationame is repeating like loc2, then show 1 record.
I want result like following.

```
locationName    itemnumber  pickRouteOrder
     loc1            item1           10
     loc2            item2           20
     loc4            item5           30
     no-loc          item6           99
     no-loc          item7           99
```

Which query i need to use in order to get desired result.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: _"If locationame is repeating like loc2, then show 1 record"_ **Which** 1 record, based on what logic? The one that alphabetically sorts lowest, presumably? But don't make people guess what you want. And what if there are multiple rows per `locationName` but their `pickRouteOrder` differs? What should be returned then?

Comment: 1) What have you tried and where exactly are you going wrong? We are not a Query Writing Service. 2) You say "show 1 record", but *which one* do you want? Do you just want one at random?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select locationName, itemnumber, pickRouteOrder
from t
where locationName = 'NoLoc'
union all
select locationName, min(itemnumber), min(pickRouteOrder)
from t
where locationName <> 'NoLoc'
group by locationName;
```

Another approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select locationName, itemnumber, pickRouteOrder
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by locationName order by locationName) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or locationName = 'NoLoc';
```